# Tracking Chromeless Flash Video Player Events using Adobe DTM

Tags: flash, adobe-analytics, brightcove

We have a brightcove Chromeless Video Player newly created in Flash to be tracked. I got the reference of [Tracking JW Player Video Events using Adobe DTM](http://www.maassmedia.com/blog/tracking-jwplayer-you-tube-flash-videos-dtm/) but I don't see any documentation on the brightcove Chromeless Video Player (Flash) with DTM. Any idea please share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://sevarum.com/2014/06/omniture-integration-brightcove-video/) are some steps. And [here](https://blog.brightcove.com/en/2009/06/video-tracking-omniture-sitecatalyst) are some documentation.

Typically, you will need to do the following steps:

Step 1: Report suite configuration- configure your report suite to track the the milestones in appropriate variables.

Step 2: Configuring Brightcove Player- Configure the player to all script access.

Step 3: Add the parameters to the video object.

Step 4: Add the Brightcove plugin in the plug-ins section of the s_code file

Step 5: Add the media module in the module section of the s_code file.

Comment: Thank you so much for the directions. I really appreciate.